# How to change password using Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I want to change current user password using Firebase in Flutter.
Can any one help me on how to implement change password method?

Answer (score 23):

I know this is a late post, but now it's possible to change the password of the logged-in user. Make sure to notify the user to log in again since this is a sensitive operation.

```
void _changePassword(String password) async{
   //Create an instance of the current user. 
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
   
    //Pass in the password to updatePassword.
    user.updatePassword(password).then((_){
      print("Successfully changed password");
    }).catchError((error){
      print("Password can't be changed" + error.toString());
      //This might happen, when the wrong password is in, the user isn't found, or if the user hasn't logged in recently.
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 21):

If you are here for the solution in 2021 and getting reauthenticate error ->

```
void _changePassword(String currentPassword, String newPassword) async {
final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
final cred = EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    email: user.email, password: currentPassword);

user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred).then((value) {
  user.updatePassword(newPassword).then((_) {
    //Success, do something
  }).catchError((error) {
    //Error, show something
  });
}).catchError((err) {
 
});}
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. Your answer is useful when we want to reset password with checking current password.

Comment: Hello. I am trying to use your method. The login page and the password change page are different. On the password change page, how can I get the current password of the user?

Answer (score 2):

This should work according to the latest version of firebase:

```dart
final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;  
User currentUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser; 
currentUser.updatePassword("newpassword").then((){
  // Password has been updated.
}).catchError((err){
  // An error has occured.
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported.

When this pull request is merged https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/678 the Flutter firebase_auth package will support that.

Answer (score 1):

Building on **@Deepanshu Chowdhary**'s answer with a bit more error handling and some null safety (in my use case I can assume that both the user and email aren't null when I run this function, but you may need to check that first).

The function will return null if everything worked successfully, otherwise it will return a specific string for the error code where specified or just "Unknown".

```
static Future<String?> changePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) async {
    User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: user.email!, password: oldPassword);

    Map<String, String?> codeResponses = {
      // Re-auth responses
      "user-mismatch": null,
      "user-not-found": null,
      "invalid-credential": null,
      "invalid-email": null,
      "wrong-password": null,
      "invalid-verification-code": null,
      "invalid-verification-id": null,
      // Update password error codes
      "weak-password": null,
      "requires-recent-login": null
    };

    try {
      await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
      await user.updatePassword(newPassword);
      return null;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      return codeResponses[error.code] ?? "Unknown";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As **@Gunter** mentioned that the feature is currently still unavailable, you can make use of the [firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-change-password) way of changing the password for the time being.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';

Future<Null> changePassword(String newPassword) async {
  const String API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
  final String changePasswordUrl =
      'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/setAccountInfo?key=$API_KEY';

      final String idToken = await user.getIdToken(); // where user is FirebaseUser user

    final Map<String, dynamic> payload = {
      'email': idToken,
      'password': newPassword,
      'returnSecureToken': true
    };

  await http.post(changePasswordUrl, 
    body: json.encode(payload), 
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},  
  )
}
```

You can get the `idToken` by using the [`getIdToken()`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/getIdToken.html) method on the [FirebaseUser](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser-class.html) object

You can get the firebase api key under the project setting in your console

[image]

Comment: Update 2023: 

<code>
    const String changePassUrl =
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:update?key=$fbWebApiKey';

    final String idToken = await _auth.currentUser!.getIdToken();

    final Map<String, dynamic> payload = {
      'idToken': idToken,
      'password': _txtCtrlNewPass.text.trim(),
      'returnSecureToken': true
    };
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Here's the latest method to change the password in firebase futter 2022

```dart
 Future<bool> _changePassword(String currentPassword, String newPassword) async {
    bool success = false;

    //Create an instance of the current user.
    var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    //Must re-authenticate user before updating the password. Otherwise it may fail or user get signed out.

    final cred = await EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: user.email!, password: currentPassword);
    await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred).then((value) async {
      await user.updatePassword(newPassword).then((_) {
        success = true;
        usersRef.doc(uid).update({"password": newPassword});
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err);
    });

    return success;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

2023 solution
[flutter_doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)

```
//change password
  Future<void> changePassword(String newPassword) async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    if (user != null) {

      debugPrint('password has been changed');
      await user.updatePassword(newPassword);
    } else {
      debugPrint("password hasnt been changed");
      // No user is signed in.
    }
  }
```