# How to catch ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN?

Tags: flutter, error-handling

when I update the password the program crashes and requires recent login. I need to catch that error. I couldn't catch it using try and catch.
Is there any other way to catch the error?
thank you.

```
 Future changePassword(String password) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    try{
      user.updatePassword(password).then((value) {
        print("Updated Successfully");
        return true;
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("Password can't be changed" + error.toString());
      });
    }on PlatformException catch (err) {
    print(" PlatformException ");
    return false;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: can you send some code. where you wroking?

Comment: added! ................

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293129/how-to-change-password-using-firebase-in-flutter

Comment: I do not have any problem with the code.
I just want to catch the error that occurs when we do this operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re authenticate user before performing critical operations like `deleting user and updating password`

- First create an AuthCredential. here is an example if your using Email Auth:

you will need the user to provide thier previous password and store it as `userPassword`.
And you can get the email from the `user` Object

```
userEmail = user.email;

AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(
      email: userEmail,
      password: userPassword,
    );
```

Then re authenticate the user with the above credential, then perform the update

```
await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then((value) async {

  if(value.user==null){
    return false;

  }else {

    try{
      user.updatePassword(password).then((value) {
        print("Updated Successfully");
        return true;
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("Password can't be changed" + error.toString());
      });

    }on PlatformException catch (err) {
      print(" PlatformException ");
      return false;
    }

  }
});
```

To catch Error use

```
try{
      user.updatePassword(password).then((value) {
        print("Updated Successfully");
        return true;
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("Password can't be changed" + error.toString());
      });

    } catch (error){
      print('Error updating password  : '+ error.toString());
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer 
very good approach but still the same problem 
How to handle the ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD?

Comment: okay i think that is because you used an on PlatformException after the try. try catching the error with catch. I have updated the answer showing the alternative