# Flutter Change password of firebase user is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement change password for firebase user.

```
handleChangePassword(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return showDialog(
        context: parentContext,
        builder: (_) {
          return ChangePasswordPopUp(
            currentEmail: widget.email,
            auth: widget.auth,
            newPassword: (val) async {
              await widget.auth.changePassword(val);
            },
          );
        });
  }
```

The user gets reauthenticated in `ChangePasswordPopUp`and with `ValueChanged newPassword` I'm calling `changePassword`

```
Future<void> changePassword(String password) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    print(password);
    user.updatePassword(password).then((_){
      print("Succesfull changed password");
    }).catchError((error){
      print("Password can't be changed" + error.toString());
    });
  }
```

It prints the choosen new password and "Successful changes password" so everything should be fine but when I'm trying to logout and login again it is the old password which works and not the new one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably ```duplicate``` of    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293129/how-to-change-password-using-firebase-in-flutter

Comment: Don´t think so. It's now supported and user is reauthenticated before changing the password.

Answer (score 1):

```
void _changePassword(String password) async{
   //Create an instance of the current user. 
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

    //Pass in the password to updatePassword.
    user.updatePassword(password).then((_){
      print("Your password changed Succesfully ");
    }).catchError((err){
      print("You can't change the Password" + err.toString());
      //This might happen, when the wrong password is in, the user isn't found, or if the user hasn't logged in recently.
    });
  }
```